# Efficient way for sorting items for different parameters?

Tags: sorting, e-commerce

Suppose you have millions items(say search results) and you have different parameters for sorting these items(like in eCommerce sites). We will be showing the items using pagination.

Let us say it can be sorted by date, popularity and relevance and results are paginated. How would you implement this functionality? Generally I would create different compare functions for parameters and get results accordingly.

If there any other efficient way to have this kind of functionality instead of sorting the search results every time? Also, do we generally run sql query every time using relevant order parameter or should we sort the search result of previous query to save us from re-searching time?

Comment: What do you mean, "resorting the results again and again"? Do you mean actually getting the results and then sorting them? Why not just structure your database query to sort by each parameter?

Answer (score 1):

"If there any other efficient way to have this kind of functionality instead of sorting the search results every time?"

I would say you do not need sort every time but execute `SQL` query with appropriate `OrderBy` parameter, paginate it and show to the user

"Also, do we generally run sql query every time using relevant order parameter or should we sort the search result of previous query to save us from re-searching time?"

For sure you need to generate a new `SQL` query, as the first page data based on a new order parameter can contain completely different set of data from previouse one.